# How to RESTRICT a css file for only on one view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 controllers, both of them have many views.
I added a new CSS file in assets/stylesheets to apply css property to one of the views in my 2nd controller.

But when I add that CSS file to assets/stylesheets, the changes that are said are applied to every page in the application. It is affecting my layout.

The above CSS file is only linked to one view of 2nd controller.

So how could I restrict a CSS file to only one view or one controller without adding in assests folder?

Comment: Ok.  Slow down.  Take a deep breath.  Please explain that again, from the beginning, assuming that nobody knows anything about your app.  Use paragraphs.  Go into some more detail.  Don't shout.

Comment: Do you want to completely replace stylesheet A with stylesheet B on that one page, or just override some of the rules?

Comment: sorry for the confusion made, i made it more clear :)

Comment: did you add that file in /app/assets/stylesheets/applications.css by require ?
Where are you adding that file in your views ? I mean in specific view or in layout ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove *= require_tree .
 from application.css file
Create separate layout for Each View and add Following css

```
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'your-css.scss', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

Answer (score 4):

When left to its own devices, Rails merges all of your stylesheets into a single file, which is applied to every view with this line of code (probably in your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'%>
```

There are a handful of ways to change this behaviour by altering the code in app/assets/stylesheets/layout.css, and adding different stylesheet_link_tags to different views, however I would not encourage this approach. It will become messy to manage, and may be difficult ot implement in the first place if you don't already have an understanding of the Asset Pipeline. Instead, I encourage you to take this approach: give each distinct stylesheet a wrapper class (i.e. the .page1 class and the .page2 class, or the .controller1 class, etc), and then wrap your pages in elements with these classes (i.e. "Page 1" gets wrapped in a `<div class="page1"> ... </div>`).

Doing this will allow you explicit control over our styles without having to get into the nitty-gritty details of the Asset Pipeline.

If you decide you desperately need to keep your styles distinct and include them separately, I'd recommend reading [some of the documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).